# Cannot share folder in 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm going through the sharing process on a folder on my root drive to get it shared across my domain. After setting permissions levels, the process attempts to share the folder but eventually says "Can't share this folder" with no additional information. I checked permissions, owners, and everything seems to be correct. Can't find any information in the EventLog to view it. File server role is installed. I went through the netshare wizard and was able to get it shared, but when I attempted to access it through a client computer, it unmounted the share. Any ideas?

Comment: What type of folder are you trying to share?  Some special folders cannot be shared.

Comment: Just a folder that I brought over from another computer. I created a new folder and shared it, then imported everything from that folder into it and it worked fine. Weird, eh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a new share folder and dropped the contents into it - everything works correctly.